# Protecting a Sheet - While allowing changes via a double click

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet where people are to enter when something has been completed. I figured the most efficient way would be to use double click tick boxes. However, I want to pull the user ID and the timestamp for this, and don't want anyone to be able to edit **anything** except if they are double clicking something for the first time.

I have the below which works for what I need but I don't know how to protect the sheet exactly as I wish.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Limit Target count to 1
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'Isolate Target to a specific range
If Intersect(Target, Range("Ckboxes")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'Set Target font to "marlett"
Target.Font.Name = "marlett"
'Check value of target
If Target.Value <> "a" Then
    Target.Value = "a"    'Sets target Value = "a"
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("UserName")
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "a" Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Also, if I protect columns C and D then it won't let the macro enter the values needed there. I know I may need to protect the whole worksheet and have it unlock the cells upon a double click to allow the change to happen and then lock again straight after but I can't figure out how to manage that!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, to unprotect the sheet is just sheet.unprotect so put that before the write to cell then just sheet.protect afterwards?

Comment: How is your intersect working? Are the boxes embedded into cells and don't need to be referred to as shapes?

Comment: There are no boxes - it simply types an `a` in the box and the font shows it as a tick. The `.unprotect` worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is protect the sheet as usual and put in the check-boxes. Then assign this macro to all the checkboxes -

```
Sub ChkBxClk()
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

If shp.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
    MsgBox ("This was already checked off")
    shp.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
    Exit Sub
End If

If shp.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address)
            rng.Offset(0, 1).value = Environ("UserName")
            rng.Offset(0, 2).value = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
End Sub
```

Now, if a user checks a box (which is allowed on a protected sheet), it will unlock and allow you to enter what you want in the offset cells.